# Jackson Custom Serializer simplification

Tags: java, kotlin, jackson

I have a payload like this:

```json
items: [
{
   "foo" : "baz",
   "whatever" : "thing"
}
]
```

Literally, all I have to do is just navigate to `/items/0` and then continue the normal deserialization process. But I don't see how I can do that with the current JsonDeserializer.

```
class BugDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Bug>() {
    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser?, ctxt: DeserializationContext?): Bug {
        val node: TreeNode = p!!.readValueAsTree()

        val correct = node.at("/items/0")
        
        // Now what? 'correct' has no `readValueAs` method
        return p.readValueAs(Bug::class.java)

    }
}
```

Once I navigate properly, I don't see anyway to thus "continue". I have gone so far as to instantiate another `ObjectMapper` to do the job, but this doesn't work either because I have the deserializer directly on my `Bug` class, so it gets invoked twice.

How do I simply deserialize normally, once I've navigated to the correct json path?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Right way to write JSON deserializer in Spring or extend it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11376304/right-way-to-write-json-deserializer-in-spring-or-extend-it)

Comment: You could deserialize it as an List<Bug> containing just one element. If you want I can write an answer involving java code (I don't know kotlin).

Comment: @dariosicily - that could prove instructional. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you have an input `{"items": [{"foo" : "baz","whatever" : "thing"}]}` json file and you want to deserialize it to a `Bug` list where `Bug` class is like `data class Bug(var foo: String, var whatever: String)` you can use [`TypeReference`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.12/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) to instantiate reference to the generic type `List<Bug>` like below:

```
data class Bug(var foo: String, var whatever: String)

fun main() {
    val mapper = ObjectMapper().registerKotlinModule()
    val json = """
       {"items": [
        {
           "foo" : "baz",
           "whatever" : "thing"
        }
        ]}
    """.trimIndent()

    val items: JsonNode = mapper.readTree(json).get("items")
    val bugs: List<Bug> = mapper.convertValue(items, object: TypeReference<List<Bug>>(){})
}
```

*Edit*:
A simpler solution converting a json array into a `Array<Bug>` object can be obtained using the `com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue` with one line:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.jacksonObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.kotlin.readValue

fun main() {
    val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
    val json = """
       {"items": [
        {
           "foo" : "baz",
           "whatever" : "thing"
        }
        ]}
    """.trimIndent()
    val items: JsonNode = mapper.readTree(json).get("items")
    val bugs = mapper.readValue<Array<Bug>>(items.toPrettyString())  
}
```

Comment: I was looking for something more seamless like: `mapper.readValue(json,Bug[].class)` hence the deserializer. But really, it's just one extra line of code instead of a deserializer. Maybe I am just over complicating it

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno, probably my update is more similar to what you are expecting than my previous solution.

Comment: Your edit doesn't contain `items:[]` which is the whole problem. Otherwise it would just work

Comment: @ChristianBongiorno Added the `items` label to the array.

Answer (score 0):

To override custom deserialiser and provide your own you need to use `BeanDeserializerModifier`. You can find example here:

- [How to ignore type information on json arrays during jackson deserialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55363266/how-to-ignore-type-information-on-json-arrays-during-jackson-deserialization)

Also you can implement a new custom deserialiser, skip the beginning of `JSON` payload, deserialise to an inner class and return what you want. It could look like below:

```kotlin
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.type.SimpleType

class BugJsonDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<Bug>() {

    private val innerBugType: JavaType = SimpleType.constructUnsafe(InnerBug::class.java)

    override fun deserialize(p: JsonParser, ctxt: DeserializationContext): Bug {
        p.nextToken() // start object
        p.nextToken() // field name
        p.nextToken() // start array

        val innerDeser: JsonDeserializer<*> = ctxt.findNonContextualValueDeserializer(innerBugType)
        val (foo, whatever) = innerDeser.deserialize(p, ctxt) as InnerBug

        return Bug(foo, whatever)
    }

    private data class InnerBug(
        val foo: String? = null,
        val whatever: String? = null
    )
}
```

You need to register above deserializer:

```kotlin
@JsonDeserialize(using = BugJsonDeserializer::class)
data class Bug(
...
```

See also:

- [[Bug] A data class that has an inline class-typed property can't be deserialized](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-kotlin/issues/413)